# Center text in div with background not 100% width

Tags: html, css

I'm using Bootstrap 3.

I need to center a text (h2) in a div with a background. I need that his background not 100% width.

I cannot center them in their column(s) (see screenshot of wrong behavoiur).

[image]

This is HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="category-title">

                <h2>{{ @value->category }}</h2>

            </div>

</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
    div.category-title{display:inline-block;
background-color:#E1001A;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto}

div.category-title > h2{color:#FFF;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:200%;}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add class `text-center` to the parent element of `category-title`

```css
div.category-title {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #E1001A;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
div.category-title > h2 {
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">

    <div class="category-title">

      <h2>Offerte Pala</h2>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">

    <div class="category-title">

      <h2>Offerte Pala</h2>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-center` in div class. Something like following.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <div class="category-title">
            <h2>{{ @value->category }}</h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, unlocking a door with a grenade works too. Doesn't mean it should be done. This is better now with your text-center class. :)

Comment: Is `align="center"` so dangerous as to be compared with a grenade? Anyways rectified the issue with `text-center` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try `class="text-center"` from official Bootstrap site. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

```
<p class="text-left">Left aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-center">Center aligned text.</p>
<p class="text-right">Right aligned text.</p>
```